# BigTop docker-hadoop.sh failing to start

Tags: ruby, hadoop, apache-spark, docker, bigtop

I'm using BigTop 1.2.0 the vagrant provisioner is running fine but when I try to use the Docker provisioner the following error is showing:

Command

> $ ./docker-hadoop.sh -c 3

Error

> Environment check... 
>   Check docker:
>   Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4 
>   Check docker-compose:
>   docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac219 
>   Check ruby: ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]
>   -e:1:in `<main>': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>   -e:1:in `<main>': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) 
>   The scale command is deprecated. Use the up command with the --scale flag instead. 
>   Creating 20171020215450r21863_bigtop_1 ...
>   Creating 20171020215450r21863_bigtop_2 ... 
>   Creating 20171020215450r21863_bigtop_3 ...
>
> ERROR: for 20171020215450r21863_bigtop_2  Resource ID was not provided
>   ERROR: for 20171020215450r21863_bigtop_3  Resource ID was not provided
>   ERROR: for 20171020215450r21863_bigtop_1  Resource ID was not provided
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "docker-compose", line 6, in 
>      File "compose\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
>      File "compose\cli\main.py", line 121, in perform_command
>      File "compose\cli\main.py", line 796, in scale
>      File "compose\service.py", line 257, in scale
>      File "compose\service.py", line 444, in _execute_convergence_start
>      File "compose\service.py", line 395, in _execute_convergence_create
>      File "compose\parallel.py", line 70, in parallel_execute 
>   docker.errors.NullResource: Resource ID was not provided 
>   Failed to execute script docker-compose 
>   Docker container(s) startup failed!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're running docker-hadoop.sh on windows with mingw32. The Docker Provisioner is tested to work on Mac and Amazon Linux for Bigtop releases just because of the resource limitation. So I'm not quite sure what's the story at Windows side ;)

However, from your error log:

> undefined method[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I'm pretty sure that the issue is related to our ruby YAML parsing feature:
https://github.com/apache/bigtop/blob/master/provisioner/docker/docker-hadoop.sh#L138

To this end, I'd suggest you to stick with Vagrant Provisioner on Windows.
If you'd like to help us in making the feature compatible with Windows, feel free to reach out to dev@bigtop.apache.org